# Regex.Matches doesn't find match

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm using Visual C# to create a little tool to support some people doing simple text manipulations. The tool has a GUI but uses regex in the code. Most things work already but now I found a problem that I'm not able to solve. I want to find the string MY2020 at the start of a word. Here's my code:

```
string TestString = "we have the string MY2020 somewhere in the line";
string Pattern = "\bMy2020";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
MatchCollection myMatches = Regex.Matches(TestString, Pattern, options);
if (myMatches.Count > 0)
{
```

I expect MY2020 to be found. So myMatches.Count should be 1, but it's 0.
In parallel I use an online regex tester (https://regex101.com/). This one shows a match.
What am I missing?

Comment: wouldnt you use \\bMy2020? and are you sure it has a backspace in it?

Comment: `"\b"` stands for the backspace character. You need to escape the backslash

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the "\", I have modified your code as

```
      string TestString = "we have the string MY2020 somewhere in the line";
      string Pattern = @"\bMy2020";
      RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
      MatchCollection myMatches = Regex.Matches(TestString, Pattern, options);
      if (myMatches.Count > 0)
```